# Is this unsynchronized object pool implementation good/safe?

Tags: java, synchronization, lock-free, pooling

Can this object pool cause visibility problems with multiple threads? I'm specifically wondering about this kind of execution sequence:

- Thread A - obtainObject()
- Thread A - modifies object (lets say visibleState = 42)
- Thread A - releaseObject()
- Thread B - obtainObject() (get the object just released by A)
- Thread A - does something unrelated or dies
- Thread B - modifies object (lets say visibleState = 1)
- Thread B - print objects visibleState
- Thread B - releaseObject()

Could the modification from Thread A possibly become visible to Thread B *after* B has modified the state itself? (I know it doesn't occur in practice, but I can't figure out if and how the JLS/Javadoc guarantees this).

Here's the code, stripped down to only show the essentials. I left out generification and a factory to create objects.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class ObjectPool {

/** Maximum number of objects to be kept in pool */
int maxPoolSize = 10;

/** First object in pool (LIFO queue) */
final AtomicReference<PoolableObject> firstObject = new AtomicReference<PoolableObject>();

/** How many objects are currently in the pool */
final AtomicInteger poolSize = new AtomicInteger();

/** Gets an object from the pool. If no object is available
 * from the pool, a new object is created and returned */
public PoolableObject obtainObject() {
    while (true) {
        PoolableObject object = firstObject.get();
        if (object == null)
            break;
        if (firstObject.compareAndSet(object, object.next)) {
            poolSize.decrementAndGet();
            return object;
        }
    }
    // no more objects in pool, create a new object
    return new PoolableObject();
}

/** Returns an object to the pool. */
public void releaseObject(final PoolableObject object) {
    while (true) {
        if (poolSize.get() >= maxPoolSize)
            break;
        final PoolableObject first = firstObject.get();
        object.next = first;
        if (firstObject.compareAndSet(first, object)) {
            poolSize.incrementAndGet();
            break;
        }
    }
}

}
```

The objects managed by the pool are supposed to inherit from this class:

```
public class PoolableObject {

/** Links objects in pool in single linked list. */
PoolableObject next;

public int visibleState;

}
```

Comment: There isn't really a queue here?

Comment: Do you refer to the comment on firstObject? Maybe my english fails me, but I think a single linked list can be reasonably called a 'queue'.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's not being used like a queue.  An [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) of size 1 would be much easier to use correctly, or perhaps a [`SynchronousQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html).

Comment: You lost me here. That firstObject 'points' to the first object of a list, it can be of arbitrary length.

Comment: Ah.  I see, I guess.  Honestly, though...concurrency is an area where you should bend over backwards to use pre-built, already-tested abstractions, because it's _so_ hard to be sure that you've got it right.  [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) does the same thing you appear to be trying to do, but it's been exhaustively tested and optimized, and its locking properties have proofs attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as visibility goes, [`AtomicReference` has the same memory barrier properties as a `volatile` variable.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html#package_description)

Among those properties are that all actions of a thread before a write to a volatile variable *"happen-before"* that write. Or, to put it another way, if source code shows an action happening before a volatile write, that action can't be re-ordered by the JITC to occur after the volatile write. Thus, the scenario cited in the question won't be a problem; changes to the object made before it is released will be visible to other threads that subsequently capture the object.

However, I don't completely follow the way this pool is supposed to work, and there could be other problems. In particular, I'm not convinced that the lack of atomicity between `firstObject` and `poolSize` is safe. Threads can definitely see these variables in an inconsistent state, because they are not `synchronized`; I can't tell if that matters though.

Comment: Ah, I did miss the 'volatile' barrier property of AtomicReference. So in essence, any memory modifications that A performed before accessing the AtomicReference are guaranteed to be visible to B after its access to the AtomicRef. That perfectly clears up my question.As for the poolSize, yes its not perfectly synched with the real pooled object list. For my purposes, I consider that an unavoidable inaccuray, but the only effect of that should be that the set pool size is not obeyed accurately, which doesn't bother me.

Comment: @Durandal: Possibility of inconsistencies between `firstObject` and `poolSize` can be eliminated by using `AtomicStampedReference` to store both reference and size.